# Session in generic handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, handler

I have the following simple handler (removed some code for vissibilty sakes, but the below still fails)

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="DownloadHandler" %>
using System;
using System.Web;

public class DownloadHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Session["t1"] != "true")
        {

        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The line `if (context.Session["t1"] != "true")` is failing with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." and i dont quite get why that is?

Comment: What object is `null`? Is it `context` or `context.Session`?

Comment: Sorry - found the answer to my own question.

`IRequiresSessionState` should be added (like `public class DownloadHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because for http handler in order to access `Session` you need to explicitly implement `IRequiresSessionState` interface.

Keep in mind that if you do that there will be an implicit locking on the session object and you won't be able to have multiple handlers in the same session state processed simultaneously.

There is an `IReadOnlySessionState` interface as well for read-only session state access.

Comment: i am facing same problem i used iRequiresSessionState in my handler code but still i can't access session values. session keys are still 0. can anyone tell me about this?